# how to flush the ZipOutputStream periodically in java

Tags: java, memory, zip

I am trying to archive list of files in zip format and then downloading it for the user on the fly...

I am facing out of memory issue when downloading a zip of 1gb size

Please help me how i can resolve this without increasing jvm heap size. i would like to flush the stream periodically..

I AM TRYING TO FLUSH PERIODICALLY BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME.

Please find my code attached below:

```
try{
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(out);

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\"ResultFiles.zip\"");
                  //adding multiple files to zip
        ZipUtility.addFileToZip("c:\\a", "print1.txt", zip);
ZipUtility.addFileToZip("c:\\a", "print2.txt", zip);
ZipUtility.addFileToZip("c:\\a", "print3.txt", zip);
ZipUtility.addFileToZip("c:\\a", "print4.txt", zip);

zip.flush();        
zip.close();
out.close();
} catch (ZipException ex) {
            System.out.println("zip exception");             
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();   
}
```

---

```
public class ZipUtility {

    static public void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,
            ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception {

        File file = new File(path + "\\" + srcFile);
        boolean exists = file.exists();
        if (exists) {

            long fileSize = file.length();
            int buffersize = (int) fileSize;
            byte[] buf = new byte[buffersize];

            int len;
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path + "\\" + srcFile);
            zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile));
            int bytesread = 0, bytesBuffered = 0;
            while ((bytesread = fin.read(buf)) > -1) {
                zip.write(buf, 0, bytesread);
                bytesBuffered += bytesread;
                if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) { //flush after 1mb
                    bytesBuffered = 0;
                    zip.flush();

                }
            }
            zip.closeEntry();
            zip.flush();
            fin.close();
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: is there any compression in the zipoutputstream? if yes, then you can't flush it.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use chunked encoding to send a file that large otherwise the servlet container will try and figure out the size of the data you are trying to send before sending it so it can set the Content-Length header.  Since you are compressing files you don't know the size of the data you're sending.  Chunked-Encoding allows you to send pieces of the response in smaller chunks.  Don't set the content length of the stream.  You might try using curl or something to see the HTTP headers in the response your getting from the server.  If it isn't chunked then you'll want to figure that out.  You'll want to research how to force the servlet container to send chunked encoding.  You might have to add this to the response header to make the servlet container send it chunked.

```
response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

The other option would be to compress the file into a temporary file with File.createTemp(), and then send the contents of that.  If you compress to a temp file first then you can know how big the file is and set the content length for the servlet.

Comment: i tried seeting the response in my code   response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");  but i dont work

Comment: Well you'll need to figure out if your server is trying to send this file in chunked encoding or not.  If it's already sending it chunked and you still have the problem then I bet it's something with using zip.  I'd try using CURL or a web browser to look at the headers in the response when the user tries to download the file.  See if transfer-encoding is chunked (without you setting the parameter in your response).  If its present in the header then that's not the problem, and it's probably how you're using Zip.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are digging in a wrong direction. Try to replace the servlet output stream by a file stream and see if the issue is still here. I suspect your web container tries to collect whole servlet output to calculate content-length before sending http headers.

Comment: Also, I guess you have to flush servlet stream, but not the zip stream.

Comment: flushing the zip stream will flush the servlet stream.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing...you are performing your close inside your try catch block. This leaves the chance for the stream to stay open on your files if you have an exception, as well as NOT giving the stream the chance to flush to the disk.

Always make sure your close is in a finally block (at least until you can get Java 7 with its try-with-resources block)

```
//build the byte buffer for transferring the data from the file
//to the zip.
final int BUFFER = 2048;
byte [] data = new byte[BUFFER];

File zipFile= new File("C\:\\myZip.zip");

BufferedInputStream in = null;
ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;

try {
  //create the out stream to send the file to and zip it.
  //we want it buffered as that is more efficient.
  FileOutputStream destination = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
  zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(destination));
  zipOut.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);

  //create the input stream (buffered) to read in the file so we
  //can write it to the zip.
  in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToZip), BUFFER);

  //now "add" the file to the zip (in object speak only).
  ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
  zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

  //now actually read from the file and write the file to the zip.
  int count;
  while((count = in.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
zipOut.write(data, 0, count);
  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  throw e;
}
catch (IOException e) {
  throw e;
}
finally {
 //whether we succeed or not, close the streams.
 if(in != null) {
try {
  in.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
  //note and do nothing.
      e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
 if(zipOut != null) {
try {
      zipOut.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
      //note and do nothing.
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Now if you need to loop, you can just loop around the part that you need to add more files to. Perhaps pass in an array of files and loop over it. This code worked for me zipping a file up.

Comment: Bcos i was able to download the zip archive if the zip size is less i.e around 160mb..

Comment: I've had 12 MB worth of stuff zipped up. I could try a gigabyte. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Don't size your `buf` based on the file size, use a fixed size buffer.