# Java IO . How to make file to zip file byte[]?

Tags: java-io

I want to make the file to zip . I can make the file to zip file but I don't want to create temporary zip file. Is any way to make the file to zip and to byte[] ? 
Thanks

Comment: Why? Are you aware you can write it directly to any `OutputStream`, not just a file? Do you *really* need the entire ZIP file in memory? It's not an approach that will scale.

Comment: I'm working on a web project ,i need to zip the files and let users download it , so i think make the files to zip and store it in disk and deleted the temporary zip is a spot of bother. So i decided make the zip file in memory   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zip files are typically generated with streams anyway, so there's no need to temporarily store them in a file - might as well be in memory or streamed directly to a remote recipient (with only a small memory buffer to avoid a large memory footprint). 
Ref Sample helperclass in the accepted answer section [How can I generate zip file without saving to the disk with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406148/how-can-i-generate-zip-file-without-saving-to-the-disk-with-java)

Comment: Thanks (●'◡'●)  It's really helpful.