# Java: how to compress a byte[] using ZipOutputStream without intermediate file

Tags: java, arrays, compression, zipoutputstream

Requirement: compress a byte[] to get another byte[] using java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream BUT without using any files on disk or in-memory(like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406927/9132186). Is this even possible?

All the examples I found online read from a file(.txt) and write to a file(.zip). ZipOutputStream needs a ZipEntry to work with and that ZipEntry needs a file.

However, my use case is as follows: I need to compress a chunk (say 10MB) of a file at a time using a zip format and append all these compressed chunks to make a .zip file. But, when I unzip the .zip file then it is corrupted.

I am using in-memory files as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406927/9132186 to avoid files on disk but need a solution without these files also.

```
  public void testZipBytes() {
    String infile = "test.txt";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(infile);

    String outfile = "test.txt.zip";
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

    byte[] buf = new byte[10];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
      out.write(zipBytes(buf));
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
  }

  // ACTUAL function that compresses byte[]

  public static class MemoryFile {
    public String fileName;
    public byte[] contents;
  }

  public byte[] zipBytesMemoryFileWORKS(byte[] input) {
    MemoryFile memoryFile = new MemoryFile();
    memoryFile.fileName = "try.txt";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(memoryFile.fileName);
    entry.setSize(input.length); 
    zos.putNextEntry(entry); 
    zos.write(input);
    zos.finish();
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }
```

Scenario 1:
if test.txt has small amount of data (less than 10 bytes) like "this" then `unzip test.txt.zip` yeilds `try.txt` with "this" in it.

Scenario 2:
if test.txt has larger amount of data (more than 10 bytes) like "this is a test for zip output stream and it is not working" then `unzip test.txt.zip` yields `try.txt` with broken pieces of data and is incomplete.

this 10 bytes is the buffer size in testZipBytes and is the amount of data that is compressed at a time by zipBytes

Expected (or rather desired):
1. `unzip test.txt.zip` does not use the "try.txt" filename i gave in the MemoryFile but rather unzips to filename test.txt itself.
2. unzipped data is not broken and yields the input data as is.
3. I have done the same with GzipOutputStream and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Requirement: compress a byte[] to get another byte[] using java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream BUT without using any files on disk or in-memory(like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406927/9132186). Is this even possible?

Yes, you've already done it.  You don't actually need `MemoryFile` in your example; just delete it from your implementation and write `ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("try.txt")` instead.

But you can't concatenate the zips of 10MB chunks of file and get a valid zip file for the combined file.  Zipping doesn't work like that.  You could have a solution which minimizes how much is in memory at once, perhaps.  But breaking the original file up into chunks seems unworkable.

Comment: wow, thanks for the fast reply. 

I did remove the MemoryFile as you suggested. But part of my problem is still unsolved. Scenario 2 still does not work.

By "you cant concatenate" did you mean I just cant keep a buf = new byte[10] and stitch to make a valid .zip

Problem in my use case I dont even have the entire input file. I have just chunks of data at a time in-memory that i need to compress and stitch these compressed blocks to make a valid .zip file. And i guess you are saying this is not possible. Please correct me if Im getting it wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that you can't do that.  You can take the chunks one by one and feed them gradually through to the *same* `ZipOutputStream`, but can't stop and start otherwise.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried using the same ZipOutputStream and same ByteArrayOutputStream and same ZipEntry. But kept the while loop to read chunks of input file into a new buffer `buf` and zos.write(buf). But `unzip` says `End-of-central-directory signature not found.`.

Comment: Please ask a new question with the complete new implementation.

Comment: posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289073/java-zipoutputstream-to-compress-chunks-of-data-to-single-zip-file

thanks for your help on this one.